# Replace all letters which is not between square bracket in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace all letter by "a" in string which is not between square brackets in javascript.

```
let value = "foo[bar9]12a"; 
// should be replaced by "aaa[bar9]12a"

let value = "[foo]bar5[foo]"; 
// should be replaced by "[foo]aaa5[foo]"
```

I tried with regex but it doesn't work like expected:

```
const value = "foo[bar9]12a";
const alphaRegex = /(?:[\d*]|\[.*\])|(([a-zA-Z]))/gmi;
const result = value.replace(alphaRegex, 'a');

// result = "aaaaaa";
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: should the 1st example not be replaced with: `"aaa[bar9]aaa"` instead of `"aaa[bar9]12a"`?

Comment: @DasSaffe Replace only letters, not digits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```js
const value = "foo[bar9]12a";
const rx = /(\[[^\][]*])|[a-z]/gi;
const result = value.replace(rx, function($0, $1) { return $1 || 'a'; });
console.log(result);
```

The `/(\[[^\][]*])|[a-z]/gi` regex matches all occurrences (in a case insensitive way) of

- `(\[[^\][]*])` - Capturing group 1: `[`, 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
- `|` - or
- `[a-z]` - an ASCII letter.

If Group 1 matched, the return value is the captured substring, else, `a`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to match a non-bracket character, then lookahead for non-bracket characters eventually followed by a `[` or the end of the string:

```js
const value = "foo[bar9]12a";
console.log(
  value.replace(/[^[\]](?=[^[\]]*(?:\[|$))/g, 'a')
);
```

Comment: With `.replace(/[^[\]](?=[^[\]]*(?:\[|$))/g, 'a')`, `foobar9]12a` turns into `foobar9]aaa`